# Not able to authenticate in Azure Hybrid Connection Manager

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication, azure-hybrid-connections

I am trying to setup connection in Hybrid Connection manager and getting below error message.

As per some post I am supposed to logged in to "https://aka.ms/mysecurityinfo" for Edge. I am logged in to in two browsers(Edge and Chrome) I use but its still not working.

This error is coming after I am successfully logged in to my azure account

**First Screen:**

[image]

**Second Screen:** After clicking on "Next" button got below screen.

[image]

Comment: Could you try disabling **Security defaults** option in your tenant like [this](https://i.imgur.com/JC4LkRy.png)?

Comment: @Sridevi Thanks for the input. Its already disabled

Comment: @RaviKhambhati Could you find an answer to this problem in the meantime?

Comment: @desolat No I did not